# Why is there a generic folder icon for Library in the "Go" menu?

Tags: macos, finder, icon, library

Usually, when in the `Go` menu in `Finder`, there are icons for each item, for example[image: Go Menu]

However, when I hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key and Library shows up, it has a generic folder icon instead of a court-like icon:

[image: Library]

I have since upgraded to El Capitan, but it has been that way since Yosemite. The only thing I can think of that may have caused this is setting the `~/Library` folder to `nohidden` using `chflags`, but setting it back to `hidden` does not fix the issue.

Is this new behavior(I doubt it), or a glitch on my part? How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no Sidebar icon for the Library folder in Yosemite and El Capitan. The sidebar icons are used for the `Go` menu items as well.

The icon that was used in the past in the  (Mavericks and before), was (to my knowledge) `ToolbarLibraryFolderIcon.icns`, which does not exist anymore.

You can view the Sidebar icons that do exist in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources`. They are named in the format `Sidebar<FOLDERNAME>Folder.icns`.

Interestingly, the Library folder icon (for the folder itself in Finder) does still exist, as `LibraryFolderIcon.icns`

Comment: +1(when I have the rep), but if I create the `ToolbarLibraryFolderIcon.ics`, will the library icon be back?

Comment: Not likely, the systems handling the icons wouldn't be looking for it.